# ArgumentOutOfRangeException when returning to page containing List

Tags: windows-phone-7, list, exception, data-binding

I am having a simple list of todo's that's stored in a List-object, that's shown through a ListBox through data binding. The items are clickable, and they take you to a details page, where you can also delete the task. Everything works out fine, but when I click the back-button, I get an ArgumentOutOfRangeException and the app crashes.

Now, I gather this is because the app thinks the list still has items, but I'm not quite sure how to fix it.

The exception is raised on System.Windows.dll - nothing specific. Also, I know the exception is raised after the OnNavigatedTo-event.

XAML (just the listbox - somewhat simplified):

```
<ListBox Name="MyActivitiesList" ItemsSource="{Binding MyActivities}" SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ListBoxItem>
                <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,12">
                    <-- context menu was here, but has been removed -->
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Style="{StaticResource BigHeader}"/>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Category.Name}" Style="{StaticResource SubtleText}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text=" - " Style="{StaticResource SubtleText}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding VotesPercentage}" Style="{StaticResource SubtleText}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="% positive" Style="{StaticResource SubtleText}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </ListBoxItem>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Code-behind:

```
private MyActivitiesViewModel myActivitiesViewModel;

public MyActivitiesView()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    myActivitiesViewModel = new MyActivitiesViewModel();
    this.DataContext = myActivitiesViewModel;
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
}

protected override void OnNavigatingFrom(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
{
    MyActivitiesList.SelectedItem = null;
    base.OnNavigatingFrom(e);
}

private void ListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (((ListBox)sender).SelectedItem != null)
    {
        var idea = ((ListBox)sender).SelectedItem as Idea;
        ((ListBox)sender).SelectedItem = null;

        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => NavigationUtility.Navigate(new Uri("/View/IdeaView.xaml", UriKind.Relative), idea));

    }
}
```

Any ideas? Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try changing `MyActivitiesList.SelectedItem = null;` to `MyActivitiesList.SelectedIndex = -1;`. and while doing so take care about SelectionChanged event handler

Comment: Even removing the entire dependency on SelectedItem/Index and using a tap event did not do anything towards my problem

Comment: `The exception is raised on System.Windows.dll - nothing specific` Don't you have a callstack?

Comment: Sound like you need to save the list to IsolatedStorage and then clear the list in the OnNavigatedFrom method, and the OnNavigatedTo you load the file and re-construct the list.

Comment: @KooKiz - Nope, nothing. That's what's making this a bit hard to debug.

Comment: @Joel - That is done behind the scenes already. The list is fetched from IsolatedStorage on start up and close, and maintained in a controller-class during execution. The list is working fine though, so it's nothing wrong there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem might be that you are deleting an item from the list while that same item is bound to the current item in the list box.

One easy way to workaround this is to use an ObservableCollection instead of a List - the collection will tell the list box about any deletion using the INotifyCollectionChanged mechanism.

Comment: Guess that could be it - however, if I fire the onPropertyChanged-event for the list itself manually when I update the list (i.e. delete something from it), wouldn't that give the same effect?

Comment: Depends on whether whoever wrote the control did a check for `if (existing==new) return;` as an optimisation... It's not hard to implement `INotifyCollectionChanged` yourself if you don't want to use ObservableCollection - e.g. at a trivial level you can just fire `Reset` whenever anything happens.